# Should nouns borrowed from Japanese be pluralized?

Tags: grammatical-number, loanwords

As someone who has watched a lot of subtitled Japanese animation, it seems odd to hear a word such as *ninja* (used in the plural) in the dialogue and see it transliterated as *ninjas*.

It somehow seems better to me to treat *ninja* just like *antelope*, *bison*, *buffalo*, *caribou*, *deer*, *elk*, *fish*, *grouse*, *quail*, *reindeer*, *sheep*, *swine*, etc., which are both singular and plural.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170/was-the-usage-spaghetti-were-ever-acceptable-or-common

Comment: I don't think the ninja will be happy when you treat him like a sheep.

Comment: As someone who is posting on an English usage site, it is  a good idea to avoid dangling modifiers.

Comment: @Gary: Are you asking specifically about American English as some of the answers seem to assume? Or all English?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Would you also insist that Japanese speakers pluralize English words when used in the plural?

Once a word has been borrowed into a language, it adheres to the grammar for normal words in that language. We don't borrow Japanese grammar, just words, so there is no need to use a zero plural with borrowed Japanese words.

It is true there is a small set of animal nouns in English that have a zero plural, but they are not borrowed and are a special case.

This is borne out by the results in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, which has 68 incidences of "ninjas". Of the 496 incidences of "ninja", there are a handful of uses of "ninja" as a zero plural, as OP suggests, from the script for the 2003 film *The Last Samurai*, but the vast majority are singular (or attributive) usage. So it does appear that zero-plural "ninja" is used, albeit uncommonly so.

So yes, *ninja* meaning *ninjas* is a usage that gets some use, but regular pluralized *ninjas* is more common, and perfectly grammatical.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer makes a good point.

Comment: In New Zealand English though, there is a big thing about not pluralising words that have been borrowed from Māori. For instance, a lot of publications will say "5 kiwi" instead of "5 kiwis", or "5 tui" instead of "5 tuis". Personally, I hate adhering to rules from other languages when speaking English, so I always pluralise them.

Comment: @Vincent: that reminds me of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/new-zealand-pronunciation-of-women-vs-woman).

Comment: @Vincent: with the **big** difference that Māori is an official language of NZ!

Comment: I'm just glad that Japanese don't insist we use [counter words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word)!

Comment: Do we follow the convention with regard to words borrowed from Gk; L; Fr; Sk; and countless other older and newer languages?

Comment: @Kris, that's another question entirely. Why don't you [ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it?

Comment: See the overall picture in this post: The answers encompass a wider perspective. My point is a mere generalization of the question. Why treat Japanese as special unless there's something different and specific about it?

Comment: "Insisting" has nothing to do with it. It implies that there are people in charge of how English ought to be spoken, like French has an Academy. There quite simply is nobody in a position of authority to insist. People with completely different views on the topic can insist one way or the other all they want and they're unlikely to have much influence over the English-speaking world. The best we can do is observe how people use English, as you have done with Contemporary American English. *Ninjas* does seem right. *Kanjis* and *yens* seems wrong, to me, but other people do use those forms.

Answer (score 11):

English has always had zero plurals as one of many types of irregular plural along with the regular plurals. For both borrowed and native words. So do related languages including German.

Neither transliteration nor Romance has a lot to do with it since we have nouns with both regular and irregular plural forms borrowed from Romance languages and other languages in the same alphabet and other alphabets.

In the case of *ninja*, it comes from Japanese and Japanese, like many languages, does not inflect for plural. Others are Chinese, Korean, Thai, Vietnamese, Indonesian, Malaysian, and all Polynesian languages including Hawaiian and Maori.

For Japanese it seems to relate to how mainstream a borrowed word has become in English. If it doesn't yet have wide currency or refers to something exotic it has a higher chance of retaining the Japanese (zero) plural. Here are some English words borrowed from Japanese in their plural form the way I say them, others may disagree:

- *anime* (though *animes* doesn't sound wrong)
- *bonsai* (perhaps uncountable in English)
- *futons* (never *futon*)
- *geisha* sounds better than *geishas* to me
- *hibachi* isn't common in Australia but I assume Americans say *hibachis*
- *judo* doesn't have a plural
- *kabuki* (never *kabukis*)
- *kanji* sounds right to me - I always cringe when I read *kanjis*
- *karaoke* (perhaps uncountable in English)
- *karate* doesn't have a plural
- *kimonos* sounds better than plural *kimono* to me
- *manga* (perhaps uncountable in English)
- *miso* is definitely uncountable in English
- *origami* (perhaps uncountable in English)
- *otakus* sounds better than *otaku* as a plural to me but this word hasn't gained much currency in English as yet
- *ramen* (never *ramens*)
- *sake* is uncountable in English
- *samurai* sounds slightly better than *samurais* to me
- *sashimi* (never *sashimis*)
- *shiatsu* (has no plural in English)
- *shinkansens* sounds wrong but so does plural *shinkansen*!
- *shinto* doesn't have a plural
- *sumo* doesn't have a plural
- *sushi* (never *sushis*)
- *tempura* seems to be uncountable in English
- *tofu* (never *tofus*)
- *torii* (never *toriis*, has a similar form to some Latin plurals)
- *tsunamis* (never *tsunami*)
- *wasabi* is uncountable in English
- *yakuza* (though *yakuzas* doesn't sound wrong)
- *yen* (never *yens*, which is another one which makes me cringe when I hear it)
- *zen* (has no plural)

Comment: "Never tsunamis"? The Wikipedia article *Tsunami* has 43 instances of "tsunamis"!

Comment: Although *sudoku* is derived from Japanese, it isn't a Japanese word.  If you talk to a Japanese about *sudoku* they won't understand you.  (Trust me, I've tried.)  By a curious symmetry, the Japanese word for *sudoku* is *namupure*, which is derived from the English words *number* and *play*.

Answer (score 5):

We do this all the time with Latin and Greek loan-words in English. (The former is technically not a Romance language, but rather the progenitor of them.)

e.g. Octupus -> Octopodes (Greek), when we typically use "Octopuses"

e.g. Peninsula -> Peninsulae (Latin), when we typically use "Peninsulas"

There are many, many more examples, in particular of Latin origin.

Generally, because these words have been around so long in the language, we anglicise their plural forms, rather than keeping the originals, out of convenience (ignorance?). Some will always insist to use the original Latin/Greek plurals, of course. With more recent loan-words, it is more common to keep the plural form of the original language.

My view is that we should use the plural form of the source language when known/in common use, and anglicise the word by adding -s or -es otherwise. Each to their own, however.

Comment: Incorrect pluralization can also happen when the original language is mistaken. I think "octopi" is pretty well accepted too, even though there's no reason for it to follow latin grammar!

Comment: Yeah, though that's a much rarer case. 'Octopi' is much worse than 'octopuses' in my view, as it betrays ignorance rather than convenience/consistency.

Comment: Are we to treat 'incorrect' pluralization as another word in the dictionary? Can it justify other similar errors?

Comment: @hippietrail: It looks like you misread the post, I'm afraid. I'm clearly stating *Latin* is not a romance language, but rather the ancestor of them -- via Vulgar Latin, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I think the pattern is that English speakers pluralize with an "S" when in doubt, and some of the plurals that sound doubtful in English end in "A" or "I". As another example, I hear "schemas" on a daily basis, but never heard "schemata" except when I tried it myself a few times.

Comment: In regular (esp., tech.) usage, *schemas* and *schemata* have different meanings and are both considered correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that hippietrail refers to *anime* as an English word borrowed from Japanese, because *anime* is actually a secondhand loanword: Japanese borrowed the *passé composé* form of the French verb *animer* (spelled *animé*) to describe animation, for which there was no appropriate verb in Japanese. And so, English speakers are actually using a French verb to describe a Japanese noun.

And so, for me, the plural *animes* sounds perfectly natural in English.

Comment: Actually like most words, *anime* has an even longer and slightly more complex history still. It evolved into the French word from its Latin ancestor, ultimately a form of *animō*, and Latin in turn inherited it in prehistory. We have reconstructed the ancestor as **h₂én* in what these days we refer to as Proto-Indo-European. But nobody would say English speakers are *actually* using a Proto-Indo-European word.

Comment: Good point. Though more in the nature of a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: I doubt that it came from French. Most likely it's a clipped English word like terebi(shoon), biru(dingu), Wiktionary mentioned this

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it depends on one's proximity to Japanese language and culture in everyday life. For E-J bilinguals, whether in Tokyo or LA, it is perfectly acceptable to avoid inflecting Japanese loanwords in English, especially in a code-switching context. However, the farther one travels from the Japanophonic (and Japanophilic) world, the more loanwords are moved from the "do not inflect" column to the "do inflect" column.

This is an organic, crowd-sourced process, not a hard-and-fast rule. Whereas Webster pluralizes kimono as kimonos, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kimono) offers both inflected and uninflected plurals (kimono or kimonos). Webster has no right to take my kimono off, no matter how many of them I may be wearing! :-P

In response to the rhetorical counterexample of whether Japanese speakers should pluralize foreign loanwords, I have seen this occur in E-J code-switching contexts. Also, there is the annoying example of takosu (tacos), which has no singular form in Japanese, perhaps because tako is already the Japanese word for another popular food, octopus. Takosu-wo hitotsu kudasai! (One tacos, please!) Arrgh.