# How do you decline nouns borrowed from languages with several categories for declining nouns (or none at all)?

Tags: grammatical-number, loanwords

English has two grammatical categories of number.  One is the singular, and the other is the plural.  Many nouns in English have different singular and plural forms.  When nouns are borrowed from other languages into English, the plural form in the source language comes with it (at least sometimes).  However, not all languages have the same grammatical number categories that English has.  I think that some don't decline at all for number.  Some have more categories, like the dual and the trial[1].  If you import a noun from a language with more categories, do you use any different dual, trial, etc. forms that the noun has in the source language?  What about if you import a noun from a language that doesn't have grammatical number?  Do you decline it for number using English's "default" -s/-es scheme?

This is mostly or entirely contrived (currently, anyway).

1. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Types_of_number

Comment: When we actually "import" a foreign word into English, we don't normally take account of any rules of grammatical number in the original language. Since the newly-imported word will be unfamiliar to native English speakers, they will treat it as a regular singular form, with a regular plural formed by adding -s/-es.

Comment: When you borrow a word, you don't borrow the entire grammar. The whole point of borrowing a word into English is to make it an English word, i.e. to make it obey the rules of English grammar. Of course there are always exceptions, but they are just that: exceptions. Irregular plurals are called irregular for a reason.

Comment: I voted to close as Too Localised, but in fact it should have been as a duplicate of [Should nouns borrowed from Japanese be pluralized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501/should-nouns-borrowed-from-japanese-be-pluralized)

Comment: Um, you don’t mean *declining* nouns, but *inflecting* them.  English has only two noun declensions: the unmarked form sometimes called nominative, and the possessive or genitive case.  Pronouns have a few more. The point is that declension is about case.

Comment: @tchrist: The first sentence in [the Wikipedia article "Declension"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension) is "In linguistics, declension is the inflection of nouns, pronouns, adjectives, and articles to indicate number (at least singular and plural), case (nominative or subjective, genitive or possessive, etc.), and gender."

Comment: @tchrist: English also has the oblique case (see [the Wikipedia article "Oblique case"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_case)).

Comment: @yakiv No, that’s wrong. English nouns have no such thing as an oblique case — just as I said. The ***personal* pronouns** have an oblique/objective/object case, although none of the other pronouns do. Just because you use a noun in English in a slot in the grammar that in other languages might call for an accusative, dative, ablative, locative, or instrumental case marked by an inflexional chance does not mean that English has an unmarked version of the same. It does not. English nouns have only two cases: regular and possessive, nothing more.

Comment: @yakiv ***Wikipedia?*** Like, *¿¡seriously!?* Anybody can make shit up there, and a lot of people do, as you have yourself just discovered. I’ll see your crowd-sourced Wikipeeedia and raise you [the OED — which says that *declension* is](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48271) “The variation of the form of a noun, adjective, or pronoun, constituting its different cases (see **case** n.¹ 9); inflection for case.”  Singular and plural are not different cases. Case closed.

Comment: @tchrist: [From dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/declension?s=t): "the inflection of nouns, pronouns, and adjectives for categories such as case and number."  See also [Wolfram Alpha's page about declension](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=declension) and [Merriam Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/declension).  When you think that someone is incorrect, there isn't a need to use an aggressive tone.  It really is okay for everyone to remain calm. :)

Comment: @yakiv  Complain to the OED, not to me.

Comment: @tchrist, since we're already fighting about definitions: Some would argue that English nouns don't have a genitive form since *'s* is a *clitic*, i.e. it works on the phrase level, not the lexical level. It's "The queen of England's mother", not "The queen's of England mother".

Comment: @dainichi: What about possessive pronoun like "his" and "its"?  Wouldn't they still count as being genitive?

Comment: @yakiv, I guess you can call them genitive personal pronouns or possessive pronouns or possessive determiners. These classes are overlapping and often their usage depends on context. In English, e.g. "my" only has the form "my" (and "mine" if you will), but in many other Germanic languages, possessive determiners inflect for case/number/gender themselves, i.e. they agree with both the possessor and the possessed. E.g. in German "meiner", "meinen", "meines", "meinem" etc. all mean "my".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**td,dr:** Just use English rules — ***unless*** nobody else does. Then do whatever they do.

---

Perhaps the best rule is to ignore the language of origin that we pinched the newly borrowed word from and just use the same basic English rules for all inflections (usually noun plurals), as though it were fully naturalized into English.  It’s certainly the easiest rule to remember, since you don’t have to learn the inflectional morphology of dozens of donor languages that way.

The truth is that it depends in part on how well assimilated the word is into English, and what the tradition is in the particular domain where that word is being used.  Sometimes more than  one version of a plural inflexion exists, such as both the English *indexes* and the Latin *indices* for the noun *index*, where mathematics tends to use the more conservative form.

Greek and Latin loanwords used in science and other technical disciplines often conserve their classical plurals.  Some are now relatively common words like  *species* and *series*, which due to their Latin origin (and perhaps also [other phonologic factors](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083) serve as both the singular and the plural of each. So too does French *chassis*, although at least that one has a pronunciation difference between *one chassis* and *two chassis*.

Other terms with non-English plurals whose special Latin or Greek plural forms may not always be observed outside of technical writing include such singular/plural pairs as *genus/genera, antenna/antennae, vertebra/vertebrae, mare/maria, thesis/theses, crisis/crises, emphasis/emphases, taxon/taxa, mythos/mythoi, dictum/dicta, paramecium/paramecia, phenomenon/phenomena, penis/penes, clitoris/clitorides, crysalis/crysalides, octopus/octopodes, fungus/fungi, nucleus/nuclei, radius/radii, criterion/criteria, matrix/matrices, cicatrix/cicatrices, larynx/larynges, stigma/stigmata* — and many, ***many*** more.

Some exotic inflections seem more resistant to naturalization than others, such as with *crisis > crises* and *emphasis > emphases*. I don’t know why that should be.  Loanwords that start out with classical inflections often lose them as we become more used to them.  For example, the OED observes that *specimina* was fairly common as the plural of *specimen* during the latter half of the 17<sup>th</sup> century.  However, the “special” plural form *specimina* instead of *specimens* is now so [vanishingly small](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22specimina%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) as to be virtually non-existent; you now only find it, if ever, in highly technical treatises on biology or typography.

You also sometimes see special plurals from French like *plateaux*, *châteaux*, and *tableaux*, or from Italian like *mafiosi*, *tempi*, or *paparazzi*. For whatever reason, non-English plurals for words coming from languages other than Latin or Greek don’t tend to last as long as the truly classical ones sometimes do.  My own theory is that this is because compared to your average joe, writers in the sciences are not only more “precisionist” in their writing, they also are more likely to have studied Latin (and sometimes Greek) in their own studies.

It just depends on the field, though. For example, in computational linguistics the word *corpus* comes up all the time, meaning a body or collection of texts.  In that domain, the expected form of the plural is the Latin one, so you have several *corpora*.  However, we do not (to my knowledge) use the Latin genitives unless we are forming the species name of a particular taxon. So the possessive of the singular *corpus* is  simply *corpus’s* in English instead of the Latin genitive singular *corporis*, and the plural possessive is *corpora’s* in English instead of the Latin genitive plural *corporum*. (Again, *taxa* are excepted, but those aren’t really English away; they’re “modern” Latin.)

Now and then you find some imported German nouns retain their German plurals for a little while, depending on the field. John Maynard Keynes actually used *Spielräume* for a particular philosophical term, being the German plural of *Speilraum*. Or when talking about the semi-autonomous local governmental units of Germany or Austria, each of which is a *Land*, you may see English writers using *Länder* for several of these.  But these are markedly foreign; they are unassimilated imports.  You can tell a German noun is on the road to being more fully Englished as soon as it loses its initial capital, as we see people writing *zeitgeist* in English instead of *Zeitgeist*.  If that needed to be made plural, I would not be surprised to encounter the uncapitalized version to be the Englished *zeitgeists*, as it stands out rather less than writing *Zeitgeister* would.

The OED attests hundreds of different singular-to-plural irregulars for imports, but most of these don’t last long in English.  It might have been *bruschetta/bruschette* and *pannino/pannini* right at the start, but those didn’t lost long, such now people look at you funny if you speak of “a graffito” in the singular, and it is not uncommon to get “double” plurals, like “two panninis”.

Just use English rules on loanwords’ plurals — **unless** you’re working with one that is *expected* to retain its irregular form. Those you should be able to find in a dictionary.

And the plural of *virus* is *viruses*. Always. :)

Comment: "phenomenon/phenomenon?"

Answer (score 1):

The best bet in general is to treat most imported words as English words. Using "fora" rather than "forums" (or "stadia" or "penes", etc.) comes across as affected and strained. The exception would be in academic, mathematical, medical, scientific and technical contexts, which have their own conventions. Beware of confusing plurals and possessives. The Latin plural of "opus" is "opera"; the English plural is "opuses". The possessive is "opus's" and the English plural possessive is "opuses'". It is better, however, unless you are talking about musical compositions using technical terms ("Opuses 90-97 of J. S. Bach were written during a trip to Berlin" or the like), just to say "works".

For formerly foreign words that are now thoroughly integrated as English words, use English plurals. In technical or academic work, follow the conventions of the field. In ordinary conversation and correspondence, don't force words that still seem un-English in, except where it improves clarity or is necessary in context. In such relatively informal settings, use English plurals unless the foreign plural has been thoroughly integrated as well (as in "criteria" rather than "criterions").

Comment: Welcome to ELU. +1 for this valuable answer!