# To refer to singular/plural items without knowing the actual quantity

Tags: grammatical-number

Sometimes we need to refer to something without knowing will it be singular or plural. How to write such things in formal writing?

*Version 1*

> No valid input files found.
>
> 1. Make sure the input field contains at least one ".adoc" file.
> 2. Make sure **this file (these files)** does exist.

*Version 2*

> No valid input files found.
>
> 1. Make sure the input field contains at least one ".adoc" file.
> 2. Make sure **this file(s)** does exist.

Or something different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singular or plural when there is no plural antecedent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381496/singular-or-plural-when-there-is-no-plural-antecedent) (where a full, all-possibilities version is given, and ideas about whether to go with singular or plural).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, it seems my question is a duplicate or somewhat very close. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second variation (and there's nothing wrong with *at least one*), use the indefinite article [**a**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a#h2); that's what it's meant for:

> 2. Make sure ***a*** **file** exists.

---

The fact that one file exists doesn't preclude the possibility that multiple files exist. But having at least one exist (which *a* covers) is a necessarily condition, and it's all that's required to avoid the error message in the question.

Comment: "Make sure **this** file exists." - as I understand, this is correct as well, but a little more explicit?

Comment: @johnc.j. That's right. It means you're talking about a single specific file. And while not wrong, more contexts than not would normally use *make sure **the** file exists*.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I'm not native speaker, and the phrase "than not would [...] file exists" is not really clear for me...

Comment: @johnc.j. I had just meant that it would be more common to use *the* than *this* when referring to a specific file. Although, there are some sentences in which *this* would make more sense—just not as many.