# What is the correct plural of "chaise longue"?

Tags: grammatical-number, loanwords

Is it "chaises longues" or just "chaise longues"?  Both examples exist in different dictionaries. Or should it be something else entirely?

Comment: Hello AJ01, I don't know how to say it the best way but I'll try :D your question is very basic, the answer is easily found looking up a dictionary (I just did with 2), so I'm voting to close it as General Reference. [This one](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/chaise+longue) is one of those two dictionaries I checked. I think it will help you. :)

Comment: I voted to close this as well, before seeing @Peter's answer. I didn't think there was any disagreement about this. Since there is, maybe it should stay open.

Comment: @Callithumpian: The answer @Peter provided more info than required. But that's the problem: how the question is being asked, not the answer(s). I mean, the question _as is_ is just two basic. If he asked something like "I found two ways to make the plural: which one is correct?", then it would have been a perfectly fine question, in my opinion. Maybe we/he should edit the question.

Comment: @Alenanno, @Calli, I edited the question to make it more clearly acceptable.

Comment: @JSBangs: thanks :)... EDIT: OMG, I just noticed I wrote "is two basic..."

Comment: I think this is a specific case of [Plurals of foreign words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/plurals-of-foreign-words), but it's getting more useful and interesting answers so I'm not voting to close :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this question, dictionaries disagree. *[Oxford](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/chaise+longue)* says *chaises longues*. *American Heritage* and *Encyclopedia Britannica* say *chaise longues.* And *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chaise%20longue)* says both.

The French plural is *chaises longues,* although neither pluralizing 's' would be pronounced  in French. I can't imagine anybody pronouncing *chaises* with two 's's. The default rule in English, to add an 's', produces *chaise longues*. Google Ngrams shows both spellings are quite common.

So I'd say both spellings are acceptable. For pronunciation, I can't imagine saying anything but *"shays longs"*. However, *Oxford* says the plural is pronounced the same as the singular, and *Merriam-Webster* says both *shays longs* and *shays long* are correct, so I suppose there are two correct pronunciations, as well.

Comment: Actually, *Merriam-Webster* and *American Heritage* say you don't have to pronounce the 's' in *longues* as well, so I guess there are probably two acceptable pronunciations of the plural. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: +1 Peter. 
- "chaise" being a substantive has to be pluralised.
- "longue" being the adjective qualifying the noun has to pluralised as well.

Comment: One more comment: if, as some people do, you pronounce *longues* in the French manner, ending with /ŋg/, adding an extra /z/ would sound quite peculiar to me. And to me it seems difficult to pronounce, although logically it shouldn't be any more difficult than the /ŋks/ in links. So there is a reasonable justification for not pronouncing the 's'.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Encyclopædia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/104523/chaise-longue), it is **Chaise Longues**.