# What should be the plural of “kibbutz”

Tags: grammatical-number, loanwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plurals of foreign words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/plurals-of-foreign-words)

A [*kibbutz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibbutz) is a collective community in Israel that was traditionally based on agriculture. Since this type of a settlement is unique to Israel, its name is in Hebrew and it doesn’t have a translation in other languages.

The plural of *kibbutz* in Hebrew is *kibbutzim*, which is also the form that the Wikipedia uses. However, this is not a correct English form, and when a non-Hebrew speaker reads *kibbutzim* they don’t necessarily understand that it’s the plural form of *kibbutz*.

What form is the proper English plural form of *kibbutz*: should it be *kibbutzim* or *kibbutzes*?

Comment: You might be interested in the discussion at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501/should-nouns-borrowed-from-japanese-be-pluralized, though it doesn't cover your case.

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/plurals-of-foreign-words -- but that doesn't seem to reach any meaningful conclusion either.

Comment: @andrew actually the accepted answer does come to a conclusion so I'm marking this a duplicate. Further attention in that other question will help everyone in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consulted five or six dictionaries linked from *OneLook.com*, and all listed *kibbutzim* as the only plural form, except *Cambridge*[¹](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/kibbutz) which recognized *kibbutzes* as a second plural form after *kibbutzim*.

It will be fine to use *kibbutzim*. Anyone already knowing the word is likely to know the plural; anybody *not* knowing the word will have to look it up anyway.

If this word becomes well known, it will follow the usual pattern: it will appear less and less often in italics (used to indicate a foreign word), and more and more often with the English plural form instead of the Hebrew.

Comment: +1. Much as I would have answered. The OED gives the plural as '*kibbutzim* (occasionally *kibbutzes*)'. However, the Corpus of Contemporary American English has 85 records for *kibbutzim* and the British National Corpus 14. Neither has any records for *kibbutzes*.